# Can't replace parametrized fragment values on frontend with Thymeleaf and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to replace some web page elements throught using parametrized fragments with ThymeLeaf + Spring Boot.

```
public class Admin {

private Integer id;

public Admin(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Admin{" +
            "id=" + id +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
@Controller
```

public class AdminController {

```
@GetMapping("/admin-reload")
public String reloadElementDiv(Model model) {
    Admin adminObj = new Admin(3);
    model.addAttribute("adminObj", adminObj);
    model.addAttribute("id", adminObj.getId());
    return "/fragments/adminForm";
}
```

}

resources/templates/fragments/adminForm.html

```
<div th:fragment="admin_form(adminObj, id)" >
    <form th:object="${adminObj}">
        <p th:text="${id}"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

resources/templates/index.html

```
<div th:fragment="admin_form(adminObj, id)">
</div>
```

one way:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/adminForm :: admin_form(adminObj, id)" th:with="adminObj='${adminObj}', id='${id}'">
    <p th:text="${id}"></p>
</div>
```

or
another way:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/adminForm :: admin_form(adminObj, id)">
    <p th:text="${id}"></p>
</div>
```

So, as a result I just have got only 'id' parameter on my index.html web page, but not its value id = 3, as I set in the controller class. Can anybody help me to get the value I need?

Comment: If you have a fragment like this `th:fragment="admin_form(varOne, varTwo)"`, then you can pass values to the fragment like this: `th:replace="fragments/adminForm :: admin_form(${adminObj}, ${id})"`, or also like this: `th:replace="fragments/adminForm :: admin_form(varOne=${adminObj}, varTwo=${id})"`. For more example, see the [documentation here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#parameterizable-fragment-signatures).

Comment: Just to add: Your `Admin` class contains an `id` field - so there is no need to add `id` as well as   `adminObj` to the Thymeleaf model. You can use `${adminObj.id}`.